# Displaying debugger output in the web page

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, webforms

I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve this "live", such as using an HTML5 element or similar. Quite simply, I have a number of status messages that I have written using 'Debug.Write', and running through them all lets me know that everything is working as expected (I'm not the best of debugger users).

Alas, the perils of working with one single screen mean that it's not always possible to clearly view both windows, even using snap-to-border features. Is accessing the debugger output even possible?

Comment: I think tracing would be more appropriate than debug output. Look at [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/)

Comment: Could you not just update an element on your page. e.g create a header element with a DEBUG id. then change its contents every time you need to?

Comment: @Harvey I considered that, but it would require reloading the page every time I called 'Debug.Write'... which, whilst accomplishing what I need in a redneck sort of way, is time consuming and possibly expensive too.

Comment: @Crowcoder I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Can I use some form of tracing to write debug messages? I've just tried the play version of Glimpse, and I don't see much beyond stats and file locations. I need to validate the order of certain functions and their specific outputs, not observe the latency between my page and backend.

Comment: Don't work around your limited debugging skills. There were major bugs in software history resulting from the lack of debugging knowledge. E.g. passwords made it into log files (Apple OS). Adding additional code for debugging changes the performance, may initialize other classes and potentially hides bugs. Instead, learn how to debug.

Comment: @Wolfish Have you tried AJAX? http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_example.asp

Comment: @Thomas I agree in principle, especially considering the vast range of potential holes in modern development, but I'm on a time constraint here. There is an international organisation waiting on this tool. Besides, debugging is a constant (imo) learning process.

Comment: @Harvey Perfect! Now all I need is a way to access the debug output...

Comment: @Wolfish you can write output to [Trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420(v=vs.100).aspx) just like you write output to Debug.

Comment: @Crowcoder I see that it's also possible to use 'Debug.Print' to write to a trace listener. Using this method, would I be able to see debugger events in the same fashion that I see them in VS? That is, a continually updated list of thread reports and write events, as well as recorded exceptions?

Comment: @Wolfish in the case of using the Trace Viewer, I think you would need to refresh the page to see updates.

Comment: @Crowcoder this is what I was trying to avoid, as it's relatively expensive considering everything else that I'm doing at the same time. no matter, I've temporarily settled on a remote-screen-esque solution using a mobile phone.